Apache RewriteRule redirecting to wrong protocol
So I have an incoming request scenario where I need to read a query string parameter, set a cookie from that parameter, and then strip off the query string. Easy enough and it works. Except that it introduces an additional redirect that shouldn't be necessary and it's not clear to me why it's doing so. I'm hoping someone here can see what I'm missing.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ...

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} the_cookie=([A-Za-z0-9]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [R,CO=ICFID:%1:%{HTTP_HOST}:43200:/,QSD]
</IfModule>

As mentioned, this functions just fine in that I eventually get where I need to be, but  the path looks like this:
Request:
GET https://www.example.com/?the_cookie=223FWWas4b

Response:
HTTP/2 302
location: http://www.example.com

I've lost the SSL protocol. That's fine, my ALB performs a 301 redirection so it's functionally equivalent, but I want to understand why that step is necessary. Initially, I thought that maybe my RewriteRule wasn't specific enough, so I tried again.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ...

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} the_cookie=([A-Za-z0-9]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,CO=ICFID:%1:%{HTTP_HOST}:43200:/,QSD]
</IfModule>

Same result. What do I need to do to get this first redirect to respect the protocol I used in the original request and redirect using it?
